# How to link two xml pages in Android app when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a simple app in which on home page, a button is placed. When the button is clicked, it must display a new page (xml in layout). How to do that ..

My app contains in src directory, There are two java files. 
1. Activity2
2. Main_activity
and two xml files in layout:
1. fragment_main.xml
2. Activity.xml

I want that when i click "Technical button", it should display Activity.xml page from layout..

My codes:

1. Main_Activity.java

   ```
   package com.example.vit;
   ```

   import java.util.Locale;

   import android.util.Log;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.view.Gravity;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
           ActionBar.TabListener {

   ```
   /**
    * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
    * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
    * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
    * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
    * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
    */
   SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

   /**
    * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
    */
   ViewPager mViewPager;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Set up the action bar.
       final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
       actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

       // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
       // primary sections of the activity.
       mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
               getSupportFragmentManager());

       // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
       mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
       mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

       // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
       // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
       // a reference to the Tab.
       mViewPager
               .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                       actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                   }
               });

       // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
       for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
           // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
           // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
           // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
           // this tab is selected.
           actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                   .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                   .setTabListener(this));
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
       // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
       // the ViewPager.
       mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
   }

   /**
    * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
    * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
    */
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

       public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
           super(fm);
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
           // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
           // below).
           return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           // Show 3 total pages.
           return 3;
       }

       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
           switch (position) {
           case 0:
               return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
           case 1:
               return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
           case 2:
               return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
           }
           return null;
       }
   }

   /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
    */
   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
       /**
        * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
        * fragment.
        */
       private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

       /**
        * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
        */
       public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
           PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           return fragment;
       }

       public PlaceholderFragment() {
       }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                   false);
           return rootView;
       }
   }
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(),Activity.class);
           startActivityForResult (intent,0);
       }
   ```

   }

2.Activity2.java

```
   package com.example.vit;
import android.app.Activity;
public class Activity2 extends Activity


    public void onCreate(Bundle, savedInstanceState)
{
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Activity);
    }

}

3. fragment_main.xml

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vit.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:onClick="doSomething"
        android:text="Technical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Non Technical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

4. Activity.xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/section_label"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Your request is being processed"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
this.startActivity ( intent );
```

Comment: Add a leading line and an explanation why you think this answer will work.

Comment: The error is in Activity2.java. 'package com.example.vit;
import android.app.Activity;
public class Activity2 extends Activity

{
 public void onCreate(Bundle, savedInstanceState)
{
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.Activity);
 }

}'

Answer (score 0):

Note : @**Don** already provided a correct answer, but (sorry) lack of information. Accept his answer, i only help to add some informations (which is quite long if i put in comment)

In Android, a page/screen in your apps refer to the `subclass` of `Activity`. An `Activity` always have a xml layout.

So, if you want to change from one layout (or screen/page) to others, you should change the `Activity`, with the help of `Intent` class. This will automatically change the layout (as your question refer) because an `Activity` has a layout.

No offense, but i suggest you to search some videos/books/tutorials. I suggest `Commonsware`'s book which is free (the old version, but still the best book in my opinion) :

http://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free

Answer (score 0):

all is going right but u have to include the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
this.startActivity ( intent );
```